# choosing circular shape of a matrix

Tags: matrix, random, linear-algebra

How to choose binary random elements of a matrix so that the matrix shape can be similar to a circle.(for example, '1' means presence of that element of matrix and '0' means I do not use that element and put it equal to zero)

Comment: What does your "random" mean here?

Comment: randomly choosing elements of a matrix. for example, if matrix size is 20 times by 10. randomly choose elements of this matrix. It means we have a random matrix which has values 0 and 1. 1 means we use the element and zero means we put zero instead that element. the shape for random matrix (same size) should be similar to a circle.

Comment: Pick a center and radius. If an element is within the radius to the center, assign 1, otherwise 0. Is this what you want?

Comment: How we can care more the center of matrix than 4 corners? Doesn't matter is circle or square or whatever. I just try to have more '1's in central part of matrix. I want this.